# BeanCreation Exception for Android

Tags: java, android, spring

I am getting following exception in my Android App:

> Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException:
>   Error creating bean with name 'context' defined in class path resource
>   [com/vmware/vim/binding/vmodl/context.xml]: Instantiation of bean
>   failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
>   org.springframework.core.io.ResourceEditor

My project already has reference to spring-core.jar
What can cause above issue?

Comment: You don't really tend to use Spring for Android.  Using a framework on top of a framework is a great way to get 0 performance apps.

Comment: Here I am using a third party libraries which actually using Spring.

Answer (score 0):

Some jar files are repetition. Just delete those repeated Jar.

Comment: There are no repeated jars, in case of repetition we get different kind of exception.